# Textview stops blinking after scrolling in Recycler View

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Migrated my code from listview to Recycler view using cardview. I have applied blinking effect on textview. Textview stops blinking once i scroll down and move up back.
Applying Animation in onBindViewHolder
Recycle Adapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TaskViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final TaskDetails item = list_items.get(position);


        if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ACCEPTED)) {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ENROUTE_Failed) ||
                item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ONSITE)) {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ONSITE_Failed) ||
                item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_COMPLETED)) {
            if (item.getFormList() != null && item.getFormList().size() == 0) {
                holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } else {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ACCEPTED)) {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.completeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ENROUTE) || item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ENROUTE_Failed)) {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.completeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ONSITE) || item.getStatus().equals(Constants.TASK_ONSITE_Failed)) {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (item.getFormList() != null && item.getFormList().size() == 0) {
                holder.completeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.acceptButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.onsiteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.enrouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.completeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        holder.task_subject_name.setText(item.getTask_subject_name());
        holder.task_detail.setText(item.getDetails());
        holder.task_location.setText(item.getAddress());
        holder.task_id.setText(item.getTask_id());
        holder.imageViewInfo.setTag(holder);
        holder.imageViewTaskInstruction.setTag(holder);
        holder.task_distance.setText(item.getTask_distance());


        String priority = item.getTask_priority();

        if (priority.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.JSON_VALUE_PRIORITY_HIGH)) {
            holder.list_indicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.high_priority);
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
            anim.setStartOffset(20);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            holder.list_indicator.startAnimation(anim);

        } else if (priority.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.JSON_VALUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL)) {


            holder.list_indicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.normal_priority);
        } else if (priority.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.JSON_VALUE_PRIORITY_LOW)) {

            holder.list_indicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.low_priority);
        }

        holder.acceptButton.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: Animate in onBindView() method.

Comment: Share `RecyclerView's` adapter code.

Comment: is your priority can be any other rather than above 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate view in onBind method of ViewHolder class.

```
 public class YourHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private View list_indicator;
    private ObjectAnimator anim;

    public YourHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        list_indicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_indicator);
        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(list_indicator, "alpha", 0.3f, 1f);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(200);
    }

    public void bind(DataObject dataObject){
         anim.start();
    }
}
```

Recycler adapter

```
@Override
public YourHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
    YourHolder yourholder = new YourHolder(v);
    return yourholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(YourHolder holder, int position) {
    DataObject dataObject = mDataObjects.get(position);
    holder.bind(dataObject);
}
```

Comment: once I scroll down and get back to the first item textview stops blinking. This was working fine when I was using listview.

Comment: try to remove  if(!anim.hasStarted() || anim.hasEnded())

Comment: still not working! When I scroll and view is partially visible animation works in this case but when view is completely invisible and then comes back to view animation stops working!

Comment: I corrected the answer, change Animation to ObjectAnimator and it works fine!